# AVCDecoder : Video resolution too high, reject it

Tags: android, video-encoding

I have been having some problems with mp4 video on Android . The codec is ok , the resolution is the same , but 2 different videos one runs , and the other ...

```
10-05 12:45:39.363: INFO/HTTPDataSource(8773): try to receive 65536
10-05 12:45:39.563: INFO/HTTPDataSource(8773): 65536 received
10-05 12:45:39.563: VERBOSE/MediaExtractor(8773): Autodetected media content as 'video/mpeg4' with confidence 0.50
10-05 12:45:39.563: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(8773): [U5B] setDataSource_l (350)
10-05 12:45:39.563: INFO/HTTPDataSource(8773): try to receive 65536
10-05 12:45:39.703: INFO/HTTPDataSource(8773): 65536 received
10-05 12:45:39.733: INFO/HTTPDataSource(8773): try to receive 65536
10-05 12:45:39.803: INFO/HTTPDataSource(8773): 65536 received
10-05 12:45:39.803: INFO/HTTPDataSource(8773): try to receive 65536
10-05 12:45:39.903: INFO/HTTPDataSource(8773): 65536 received
10-05 12:45:39.963: INFO/HTTPDataSource(8773): try to receive 65536
10-05 12:45:40.003: INFO/HTTPDataSource(8773): 65536 received
10-05 12:45:40.043: ERROR/QCvdec(8773): Invalid Ht[360] wdth[640]
10-05 12:45:40.043: ERROR/QCOmxcore(8773): OMXCORE API :  Free Handle 21a8b4
10-05 12:45:40.043: WARN/QCvdec(8773): ======================================================================
10-05 12:45:40.043: WARN/QCvdec(8773):                    Open Max Statistics                                
10-05 12:45:40.053: WARN/QCvdec(8773): ======================================================================
10-05 12:45:40.063: WARN/QCvdec(8773): empty this buffer rate = NaN
10-05 12:45:40.063: WARN/QCvdec(8773): empty this buffer total time = 0
10-05 12:45:40.063: WARN/QCvdec(8773): empty this buffer count = 0
10-05 12:45:40.063: WARN/QCvdec(8773): ======================================================================
10-05 12:45:40.073: ERROR/QCOmxcore(8773):  Unloading the dynamic library for OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc
10-05 12:45:40.073: ERROR/QCOmxcore(8773):  Unloading the dynamic lib done 
10-05 12:45:40.073: ERROR/QCOmxcore(8773): OMX_FreeHandle X 
10-05 12:45:40.073: INFO/AwesomePlayer(8773): calling prefetcher->prepare()
10-05 12:45:40.573: INFO/Prefetcher(8773): [0x188670] cache below low water mark, filling cache.
10-05 12:45:40.623: INFO/HTTPDataSource(8773): try to receive 65536
10-05 12:45:40.633: INFO/HTTPDataSource(8773): 65536 received
10-05 12:45:40.733: INFO/HTTPDataSource(8773): try to receive 65536
10-05 12:45:40.773: INFO/HTTPDataSource(8773): 65536 received
10-05 12:45:40.873: INFO/AwesomePlayer(8773): prefetcher is done preparing
10-05 12:45:40.923: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(8773): [U5B] play (556)
10-05 12:45:40.923: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(8773): [U5B] play_l (562)
10-05 12:45:40.933: VERBOSE/AudioPolicyService(8773): startOutput() tid 8778
10-05 12:45:40.943: DEBUG/AudioPolicyManagerBase(8773): startOutput() output 1, stream 3
10-05 12:45:40.943: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(8773): [U5B] play_l (635)
10-05 12:45:40.953: ERROR/AVCDecoder(8773): Video resolution too high, reject it
10-05 12:45:40.953: ERROR/MediaPlayer(29043): error (1, -1010)
10-05 12:45:40.953: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(8773): [U5B] pause_l (705)
10-05 12:45:40.953: VERBOSE/AudioPolicyService(8773): stopOutput() tid 29198
```

I'm sure the problem is here :

```
10-05 12:45:40.953: ERROR/AVCDecoder(8773): Video resolution too high, reject it
```

Is there any way to change resolution of a surfaceview,mediaplayer or something like that in android ?

Comment: same problem here. Have you solved it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the error you are getting is not something that can be resolved in the application, nor is it an limitation from the application.

This restriction is from the Hardware acclerated Video codec itself (`AVCDecoder` in your case). The resolution that you trying to play is too high for that particular codec.

You have also mentioned that one particular clip of the same resolution plays, you will need to verify if it is of the same codec. My guess is, it is not the same codec.

Comment: I agree some time ago , but i wasn't sure it and i needed to be sure about.